# How to check if users id = any id in JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

I tried to take data from a JSON file where someone "who typed the message" has his information with his id inside. There was nothing inside the JSON file, so it gave me error.

How do I set to that if we get an error then reply something like "you have not set anything". Or set that by the best way, that means check for ids of author.
The code I tried (`_message` goes inside tradeLinks folder):

```
let _message = client.tradeLinks[message.author.id].tradelink;
if (_message = err) {
  message.reply('You have not set the trade-link !');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let _message = client.tradeLinks[message.author.id].tradelink;
if (_message == null) {
  message.reply('You have not set the trade-link !');
}
```

Comment: @RobertKráčalík The best way to give thanks on SO is to upvote any helpful answers. As the OP, you can *also* mark 1 answer as "Accepted" indicating that it helped you the most, or you believe it to be the most useful answer amongst many provided. You can upvotes as many answers as you like. This ensures that SO functions as designed, so it's helpful to future visitors. It is also literally rewards volunteers for their contributions (through the collecting of points, values, and opportunities to gain more platform privileges).